# Node.js passport pass postdata on to failureRedirect

Tags: node.js, passport.js

This is driving me crazy!
I'm using Express 4, passport and local-passport to authenticate login and signup.

I'm using this example:
https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo

Problem:
When the signup form does not validate (say you forgot one of the fields) and we redirect to the failureRedirect (which is the same signup page), all the entered values are gone. Not a very good user experience that you have to fill out the entire form because you messed up a single field.

How do I pass the already entered data on the the form?

I got these two routes handing the GET and POST of the form:

```
app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    res.render('signup', {
        message: req.flash('message'),
    });
});

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/signup-complete',
    failureRedirect: '/signup', // need to pass the entered values (if any) back to the signup page
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

I have a nagging suspicion that the values are already there - I just don't know how to grab them.

I'm using Swig for the views btw.

Comment: I get the same problem, do you have any solution now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) middleware to your app?

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');

app.use(flash());
```

Update:

When you define your local strategy, you should return the flash messages in the third parameter of the done function. Example:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
      findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
        if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the flash middleware, but how do I flash the values when failureRedirect is invoked? It seems passport only accepts a route here. Ideally I would like an intermediate function and then do the redirect.

Comment: And the message set this proper way can be then found from `flash('error')`.

Comment: Worked as expected without needing to much gymnastics